Definable types
Let $p(x)\in S({\mathcal U})$ be a global type. Let $\varphi(x,y)\in L$.
Assume there is a formula $\psi(y)$ such that $\psi(b)\Leftrightarrow \varphi(x,b)\in p$ for every $b$.
When is the case that $\forall y\ [\varphi(x,y)\leftrightarrow\psi(y)]\in p\ $?

If this is true, then (the $\varphi$-part of) $p$ is realised.
Indeed, if $p\vdash \forall y(\varphi(x,y)\leftrightarrow \psi(y))$, then since $p$ is a type, $\mathcal U\models \exists x\forall y(\varphi(x,y)\leftrightarrow \psi(y))$. The $a$ witnessing this is a realisation of the $\varphi$-part of $p$.
The converse is not true in general: for example, in the random graph, fix an element $a$ and let $p$ be the type of a new element with all the same neighbours as $a$. Then the $E$-type is realised (where $E$ is the edge relation), but $p$ does not contain the corresponding formula (indeed, the formula is equivalent to $x=a$).
I think the converse also holds if $\varphi$ is stable.
